# Organize columns with numerical info in colnames via dplyr relocate

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tibble

I have a large amount of annual data in a data frame that will only get larger.  I would like to  organize it, grouping columns according to the year, which is included in the column names.

Base data:

```
dput(dat)
structure(list(id = 1:2, quantity = 3:4, avg_2002 = 5:6, avg_2003 = 7:8, 
    avg_2020 = 9:10, rev_2002 = c(15L, 24L), rev_2003 = c(21L, 
    32L), rev_2020 = c(27L, 40L)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I would like to do is have all of the columns with, say, "2002" in them organized together, followed by the "2003" columns and so on...I know that `relocate` in `dplyr` is a good way to do it so I did the following:

```
dat <- tibble(dat)
dat <- dat %>%
  relocate(grep("2002$", colnames(dat), value = TRUE),
           .before = grep("2003$", colnames(dat), value = TRUE)) %>%
  relocate(grep("2003$", colnames(dat), value = TRUE),
           .after = grep("2002$", colnames(dat), value = TRUE))
```

which produces the desired result for my toy dataset:

```
     id quantity avg_2002 rev_2002 avg_2003 rev_2003 avg_2020 rev_2020
  <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>
1     1        3        5       15        7       21        9       27
2     2        4        6       24        8       32       10       40
```

My question is this:

1. How do I generalize the code above so that I don't have to keep adding `relocate` statements ad nauseum?
2. Is there a better way to do this task without using `dplyr::relocate`?

Any suggestions are much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `select` - extract the numeric part of the column names, `order` it and use that index in `select` to reorder

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
   select(id, quantity, order(readr::parse_number(names(.)[-(1:2)])) + 2)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 8
     id quantity avg_2002 rev_2002 avg_2003 rev_2003 avg_2020 rev_2020
  <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>
1     1        3        5       15        7       21        9       27
2     2        4        6       24        8       32       10       40
```

Comment: what does `[-(1:2)])) + 2)` do at the end of the `select` statement?

Comment: @jvalenti because `order` returns  a index based on the subset of column names i.e. without the first two (`-(1:2)`).  By adding `+`, the index starts from 3 instead of 1.

Comment: so everything except `id` and `quantity`?

Comment: @jvalenti yes, based on the data, alll other columns have the digits in column names